# A good reference to learn the concept of partition function

Tags: statistics, dynamical-systems, statistical-mechanics

I am looking for a good reference and easy to learn the concept of [partition function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_function_%28mathematics%29) in mathematics. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

One of the standard texts in this field is The theory of Partitions by George Andrews. http://books.google.com/books/about/The_Theory_of_Partitions.html?id=Sp7z9sK7RNkC